# Pydot:AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_node_list'

Tags: python, pydot

I want to load a dot file to python,using this

```
graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_file(tmp1)

nodeList = graph.get_node_list()
```

but I got error when the label of nodes in the dot file is like:

> 398 [shape=diamond, fillcolor="#CCCCCC", label="(int)*value ==
>   '\\"'"];

error message is like this:

> ```
>   398 [shape=diamond, fillcolor="#CCCCCC", label="(int)*value == '\\\"'"];
>       ^
> Expected "}" (at char 1800), (line:34, col:7)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "dotchange.py", line 52, in <module>
>     print dotchange(line)
>   File "dotchange.py", line 13, in dotchange
>     nodeList = graph.get_node_list()
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_node_list'
> ```

It seem that the escape character `"\"` causes the error.

If I replace the label of the nodes containing `"\"` with `""`,the error disappear.

Comment: I had the similar issue  so replacing node names containing characters '<','>' as below and above was the fix.